# Twig - Why are vars defined as false become empty?

Tags: symfony, twig

Define a twig var as true, and it has a value of '1'.

Define another var as false, and it has no value. Why is that?

```
{% set myOtherVar = true %}
{{ myOtherVar }}
```

This outputs '1'

```
{% set myVar = false %}
{{ myVar }}
```

This outputs nada

https://twigfiddle.com/ebbwgf

This is bothersome because simple logic like this fails:

```
{% set myVar = false %}
{% if myVar is not empty and not myVar %}
stuff
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `false` is equivalent to `''` for `empty`. What's your goal/need with `empty`?

Comment: Oh I see, I did not realize that caveat! That explains the issue and I can work around that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`false` is equivalent to `''` for `empty`:

```
{% set myVar = '' %}
{% if myVar is empty %}
    stuff
{% endif %}

{% set myOtherVar = false %}
{% if myVar is empty %}
    other stuff
{% endif %}
```

https://twigfiddle.com/5g9thl

Depending on what you want to do, you can test if the variable exists with [`defined`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html):

```
{% set myVar = false %}
{% if myVar is defined and not myVar %}
stuff
{% endif %}
```

https://twigfiddle.com/m1n1q0

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using set to set the variable as a boolean. So you need to use it as a boolean. You can't print the value.

You might do your logic something like this:

```
{% set myOtherVar = true %}
{% set myVar = false %}

{% if not myVar %}
myVar is false
{% endif %}

{% if myOtherVar %}
myOtherVar is true
{% endif %}
```

Here is a twigfiddle showing it working properly:

https://twigfiddle.com/yxt1jd

Hope that helps!